# How to remove automatic highlighting of messages for reply in a telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

After the dialogue with the bot is completely completed in a telegram conversation, the message from the bot is automatically highlighted for the answer, how to fix this. I use telebot

````
def screenshot_request(message, bot, problem, userstate, buttons):
    if message.text.lower() == 'да':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично! Отправьте фото скриншота:')
        bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, userstate.with_screen, message.chat.id)
    elif message.text.lower() == 'нет':
        problem_message = '\n'.join(
            [f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in problem.items()])
        markup = buttons()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, problem_message)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправить обращение?', reply_markup=markup, disable_notification=True,
                         reply_to_message_id=None)
        bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, userstate.confirm_without_screen, message.chat.id)
    else:
        markup = buttons()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'К сожалению я вас не понял(( Я ожидаю ответ да/нет. '
                                          'У вас есть скриншот?', reply_markup=markup, disable_notification=True)
```[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEe0Z.jpg)


I tried using disable_notification=True. But problem like on screenshot is still available [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRQ5r.jpg)
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправить обращение?', reply_markup=markup, disable_notification=True,
                         reply_to_message_id=None) after using this part of the code, the message is always marked as a reply for another user, how to make sure that the message is not marked as a reply

Comment: or can you describe for me how to use selective in telebot